# How to keep Presenter's instance of nested Fragment while screen rotation

Tags: android, android-fragments, mosby

I faced with that problem when I started to use `ViewPager`. As every page is *nested* `Fragment`, I can't call `setRetainInstance(true)` for it. So, I need to store `Fragment`'s state to a `Bundle` and cancel/recall remote API methods `onViewAttached/Detached` which I don't want to.

What I learn about this situation:

1. **I can use [`RecyclerViewPager`](https://github.com/lsjwzh/RecyclerViewPager)** to avoid using nested `Fragments`, but I **still can't keep an instance of [`Presenter`](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-View-Presenter)**. One of the ways is to use a static field, but the same thing can I do with the `Fragment`.
2. **Create some kind of `rootViewPager` under MainActivity** and use it in `Fragments` via `setVisibility(GONE/VISIBLE)` and replacing `Adapter`. So, every `Fragment` placed into this `ViewPager` will not have parent `Fragment` and I will solve my case. Suitable and elegant, but not the best solution as I think.

Any other variants?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Mosby 3.0 Presenters can be retained even without `setRetainInstance(true)` ... I would suggest to wait until 3.0 release ...

> So, I need to store Fragment's state to a Bundle and cancel/recall
>   remote API methods onViewAttached/Detached which I don't want to.

Mosby 2.0 does exactly that for you but you have to make your ViewState and your data implement Parcelable. In that case the presenter instance won't survive screen orientation changes, but presenter will "resume" on the same state / point (a new presenter instance will be created, async tasks etc. might be restarted too). See [RestorableViewState](http://hannesdorfmann.com/mosby/static/javadoc/com/hannesdorfmann/mosby/mvp/viewstate/RestorableViewState.html) (javadoc is slightly outdated, because it mentions that this is the only way to work with activities which since Mosby 2.0 is not true anymore)

Comment: I know about RestorableViewState. I don't want to save state this way as I already build the whole architecture of my app on fragments with `setRetainInstance(true)`.

Comment: When can I expect Mosby 3 to release?

Comment: Maybe end of June, Snapshot for not retaining Fragments might be available sooner